# How to create a Horizontal Table in SAS with a data value (not variable) as a Row Item in SAS

Tags: sas

With my dataset below, I'm attempting to create 1 complete horizontal table with all 7 variables in the Columns and 1 Row of a character value "Complete" to show the frequencies for each variable.

```
District      Var1        Var2        Var3            Var4             Var5            Var6        Var7
District1   Complete Partiallycomplete Incomplete   Partiallycomplete Complete        Incomplete    Complete
District2   Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Complete
District3   Incomplete  Complete    Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete
District4   Complete    Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete
District5   Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Partiallycomplete
District6   Incomplete  Complete    Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Partiallycomplete
District7   Complete    Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Incomplete
District8   Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete
District9   Incomplete  Complete    Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Incomplete
District10  Complete    Partiallycomplete   Incomplete  Partiallycomplete   Complete    Incomplete  Incomplete
```

However, there are 2 Issues I'm facing:

1.) Inability to combine all 7 variable columns into 1 horizontal Table. SAS outputs 7 separate tables for each of the 7 variables. My attempt to include multiple "where" statements per "Proc Freq" procedure as a solution failed.

2.) Inability to have a row be a value of a Variable (Ex: "Complete").

Code I've tried:

```
proc freq data= Mon.Montest11;
Table District*(Var1)/list;
where Var1="Complete";
Run;

/* Above code works fine ONLY for 1 Variable. When I add 6 more variables as shown below, it doesn't work out */

proc freq data= Mon.Montest11;
Tables District*(Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7)/list;
Run;

/* 7 Separate tables generated*/
```

What I want:

```
                                         Var 1  Var 2  Var 3  Var 4
"Complete"                               10    20      30      40
"Partially Complete"                     20    30      40      50
"Incomplete"                             30    40      50      60
```

I've also tried Converting Character to Numeric Variables to see if that would help, but it hasn't. This may be a simple, junior-level question, but I'm having difficulty and help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please post a sample of what your data looks like. Most likely proc tabulate may work or you may have to change your data structure and then use PROC freq or tabulate. But without a good idea of your input data we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

My previous attempt didn't work but the code below has been tested and should give you the results you are looking for:

```
data want;
length district $ 20;
format district $20.;
keep district y1-y7;
set have end=last;

array c[7] ;
array p[7] ;
array inc[7] ;
array x[7] $20 var1-var7;
array y[7];
retain c p inc;


if _n_ = 1 then do i=1 to 7;
c[i]=0;
p[i]=0;
inc[i]=0;
end;
do i = 1 to 7;
  if x[i] = 'Complete' then c[i]= c[i]+1;
  if x[i] = 'Incomplete' then inc[i]= inc[i]+1;
  if x[i] = 'Partiallycomplete' then p[i]= p[i]+1;
  put i x[i] c[i] inc[i] p[i];
end;

if last then do;
do i = 1 to 7;
  district = 'Complete';
  y[i] = c[i];

end;
output;

do i = 1 to 7;
  district = 'Partiallycomplete';
  y[i]=p[i];

end;
output;

do i = 1 to 7;
  district = 'Incomplete';
  y[i]=inc[i];

end;
output;
end;
run;
```